# Getting screenshot and find location of multiple smaller images in it in linux

Tags: linux, image, x11

I want to get a screenshot of a x11 window and find the location of smaller images in it. I've had no experiences with working with images, I searched a lot, but I don't get much helpful results.

The image are from files and can be loaded with any format that is easier to use.
The getting screenshot is easy, using [XGetImage](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html). But then the question is that which format to use XYPixmap or ZPixmap? What's the difference? How each pixel is represented?

And then what about the images? Which file format is easier to use? And then how each pixel is represented in that format?

And which algorithm should I use to find the location of the images in the screenshot?

I'm really lost here. I need a push in the right direction and see some example code that can help me to understand what I'm dealing with. Couldn't find any similar work.

The language, frameworks or the tools doesn't really matter to me as long as I get it working on my ubuntu machine. I can work in either C, C++, haskell, python or javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XYPixmap, each image plane is a separate bitmap (one bit per pixel, with padding at the end each scanline). If you have 24-bit color, you get 24 separate bitmaps. To retrieve pixel value at some (x,y) coordinates, you need to fetch one bit from each of the bitmaps at these coordinates, and pack these bits into a pixel.

With ZPixmap, pixels are represented as sequences of *bits*, with padding at the end of each scanline. If you have 24-bit color, every 3 bytes is a pixel.

In both cases, there may bee padding in the end and sometimes in the beginning of each scanline. It is all described [here](http://www.x.org/docs/X11/xlib.pdf).

I would not use either format directly. Convert your pixmap to a simple 1, 2, or 4 bytes-per-pixel 2D array, and do the same with the patterns you want to search. If you want to find exact matches, you can use a slightly modified string search algorithm like [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). Fuzzy matches are tricky, I don't know of any methods that work well.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. Only upvoted now, because it doesn't answer all my questions.